# load balancing thrift traffic

Tags: load-balancing, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a client/server architect design based on thrift. Does anybody have experience on how to load balance thrift based services? I am looking for some load balancing approaches allowing me to even apply some algorithm, eg. round-robin, weighted etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but if you are using HTTP transport you might be able to use some standard HTTP proxy / load balancer like nginx or lighttpd.

But your server side implementation should not hold any state in any load balanced node, so that each of them can handle every request.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still valid, you can try this api from twitter:

http://twitter.github.com/commons/apidocs/com/twitter/common/thrift/package-summary.html